# How to connect to external server with Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)

Tags: c#, environment-variables

The following code is what I am trying to use to connect to and external server and get down to the subdirectories in the AppData folder.

```
string targetPath = @"\\externalServer\" + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Litera\\Customize";
```

While stepping through the program it comes to line 16 and fails stating "The given path's format is not supported." However, destFile shows "\\externalServer\C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Litera\Customize\Customize.xml". To me the program is finding exactly the path I want. Can someone please help me resolve this problem?

```
File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

Comment: From your computer's File Explorer (guessing Windows OS) , can you navigate manually to that exact file path: `\\externalServer\C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Litera\Customize\Customize.xml`? Because that does not look like a valid file path to me

Comment: I agree with Symon. Look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06c2b215-eca9-4fd1-b61f-7591c16f3973/how-to-copy-file-from-pc-to-server-using-filecopy-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral or https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1102764/File-from-one-computer-to-another-computer-network

Comment: In most cases, `System.IO` only calculates local file paths. Your code makes the assumption that on another machine the application data folder follows the same structure (which might not be universally true). If you manually construct the file path, it should use `C$`, not `C:`.